# Force ApexCharts to start with 0 on X axis

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I am using **ApexCharts** to render a line diagram and I want to start enumeration of labels on the X axis with `0`. So my options for the chart look like this:

```
xaxis: {
    show: true,
//  categories: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"],
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
}
```

But with these options the X axis labels still start with `1`. When I use `categories` instead, then it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What `xaxis.type` have you used? I have a feeling that min/max will only work for `datetime` and `numeric`. Could that be it?

Comment: @OscarSchafer I haven't changed the type, need numeric only.

Comment: have you got this to work?

Comment: @RihamNour No, I ended up using `categories`, which works fine in my case.